# I have a problem running this program, it keep showing "ValueError: math domain error"

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem running this program it keeps showing "ValueError: math domain error"

```
from math import tan, sqrt
R = 2.1
m = 469.4
E = 2.226
h = 6.591e-22
V = -10.0
for k in range(39):    
    V = (tan^2(R*sqrt(2*m*(E + V))/h**2))*E - E         
    print(V)
```

I expected a series of numbers like in form of iteration

Comment: Based on your initial conditions, `sqrt(E+V)` is taking the sq rt of a negative number, and so you get an error. If your formula is correct (no typos, and you intend to take the sq rt of negative numbers), take a look at the `cmath` library. But I suspect there's a typo.

Comment: And `tan^2(...)` is not taking the `tan` to the power of two, you need to use `tan(...)**2` for that. What `tan^2(...)` does is attempt to call `2` with `...` (i.e. `2.__call__(...)`) and then xor the result with `tan`, both operations will fail with an error.